# How to access filtered records after using RowFilter on DataSet?

Tags: c#, dataset, .net-1.1, rowfilter

I have a dataset on which I have set a rowfilter:

```
DateTime minDateVal = (DateTime)ds.Tables[0].Compute("Min(DateTimeField)", "anotherField = 12");

ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "anotherField=12 and DateTimeField='" + minDateVal + "'";
```

So after applying this filter, I get rows that satisfy the condition but how can I access to the filtered rows (those which satisfy rowfilter condition)?

Some doubts:

- To obtain the number of rows that satisfy the rowfilter is it correct to do below?

  ds.DefaultView.Count

  ds.DefaultView.recordCount
- To access to the rows filtered after applying rowfilter is it correct to do below?

for row 0:

```
ds.DefaultView.RowViewCache[0]["MyColumn1"].ToString()
```

for row 1:

```
ds.DefaultView.RowViewCache[1]["MyColumn1"].ToString()
```

and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You Can use `ToTable()` of Dataview to get Filtered Dataview back to Datatable

```
DataView dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

dv.RowFilter = "anotherField=12 and DateTimeField='" + minDateVal + "'";

Datatable result  = dv.ToTable();
```

Comment: ToTable is only available since .NET Framework 2.0 and I have modifying a legacy project that uses .NET 1.1... so how can I do this? using the methods I commented in my post?